# extracting values from HashMap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I was trying to learn and make understanding out of the working of a HashMap. So i created this hashmap to store certain values which upon displaying using an Iterator gives me outputs as

```
 1=2
 2=3
 3=4
```

and so on. This output i obtain using the `Iterator.next()` function. Now what my actual doubt is that since the type of this value returned in of an Iterator Object, if i need to extract only the right hand side values of the above equalities, is there any function for that? Something like a substring. Is there any way i could just get results as

```
 2
 3
 4
```

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: In most cases, interacting with the iterator directly is not necessary. See Peter Lawrey's answer to see how to make a for each loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use something like

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int value: map.values())
   System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `map.values()`.

Answer (score 2):

Map has a method called values() to get a Collection of all the values.  (the right side)

Likewise, there is a method call keySet() to get a Set of all the keys.  (the left side)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        HashMap < Integer , Integer > map = new HashMap < Integer , Integer >();

        map.put( 1 , 2 );
        map.put( 2 , 3 );
        map.put( 3 , 4 );

        for ( Integer key : map.keySet() )
        {
            System.out.println( map.get( key ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Map#values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) method which returns a `Collection`.

You can then get an `Iterator` from this collection in the normal way.